Integration by parts $\Delta g \nabla f$
Is it true that $\int \Delta g \nabla f \space dx =- \int \Delta f \nabla g \space dx $, where the functions $f,g:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth with compact support? I have tried to apply the divergence theorem but don't know how to do the trick.

Please insert brackets where appropriate, but at first sight both integrals would be $0$?

Well $\Delta g$ is a scalar, and $\nabla f$ is a vector so how exactly are you integrating this product over $\mathbb R^n$?

@Chris I think the OP should insert a few brackets to make that work.

@Chris Componentwise

Please change the order of the scalar multipication so it becomes clear that the gradient is only applied on $f$ resp. $g,$ not on what comes after. We know what a scalar times a vector means, but not what a vector times a scalar means.

Green's first identity applied to the pair $(\partial f/\partial x^j, g)$ gives
$$\int\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\Delta g=\int g\Delta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$$
Then note that the operator $\partial/\partial x^j$ commutes with the Laplacian
$$\int g\Delta\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}=\int g\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Delta f$$
Finally apply integration by parts on the $x^j$ integration variable separately
$$\int g\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Delta f=-\int \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}\Delta f$$

Thanks for answering.
